# C# how can i inline a delegate prototype?

Tags: c#, delegates

Instead of this can i write it in such a way that the definition is inside the function?

```
    delegate object ObjFunc(long c);
    static Object MyFunc(this SqlConnection conn, ObjFunc func)
    {
        return func(1);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. But you may want to use `Func<long, object>` already present in .NET 3.5.